# CutyCapt Not Displaying Custom Web Fonts

Tags: cutycapt

I'm trying to use `cutycapt` to take iPhone-sized screenshots of sites, to test a mobile app, rather than having to go and manually take screenshots every time the CSS changes.

The problem I'm running into is that `cutycapt` isn't rendering or loading custom web fonts, either served from a `fonts` directory, or by Google Web Fonts.

Example screenshot -  [Google Web Fonts](http://stwrt.ca/HqOn).

I'm running `cutycapt` using `xvfb-run` on a Ubuntu server. The command I'm using is something like this:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" \
cutycapt --url={url} --out=/tmp/test2.png \
--min-width=640 --min-height=960 \ 
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7" \
--delay=2000 --header=X_SCREEN_DIMENSIONS:640x960
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `xvfb-run` for wkhtmltoimage and had the same issue of custom fonts not rendering in the image output.

To solve the issue, I installed the custom font on my server following the instructions here:
http://www.cangjie.info/public/howto/ubuntu_fonts/ubuntu_fonts.php

I downloaded the ttf file from google web fonts and placed it in:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom/customfont.ttf
```

After placing the font, I refreshed the font cache: `sudo fc-cache -fv`

If you get a 'command not found' error trying to refresh the font cache, install fontconfig:

```
apt-get install fontconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to resolve this same problem. But it will take some time to download all of the fonts.:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-wqy-zenhei
sudo apt-get install xfs xfonts* -y
```